# Remove Columns Based On Conditions of Changing Row Name Using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm extracting tables from Wikipedia. All of my data extraction is based on a single row of the 1st column. The row is sometime named `total costs`, and sometimes `total current costs`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('', 'total costs', 'liability'),
                 col2=c("", 1000, 500),
                 col3=c("", $, ""),
                 col4=c("", $, 500,))

df1

col1            col2    col3    col4

total costs     1000      $      $
liability       500            500

============================================
df2

col1                    col2    col3    col4

total current costs     1000      $      $
liability               500             500
                                                                  ​               ​        ​
```

I want to remove the columns which have `$` sign for that particular row name -- `total costs` or `total current costs`.

I am trying the following script as suggested by [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74860065/12210377) to remove the columns:

```
row_num <- which(df$col1 == 'total costs') # or `total current costs`

df_final <- df[-which(df[row_num, ] == '$')]
```

However, I have to manually put different row name for different tables. How can I automate the process as a function so that whatever the row name -- `total costs` or `total current costs` -- it picks that automatically?

**Desired Output**

```
col1            col2
total costs     1000 # or total current costs
liability       500
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a vector at the beggining containing the different version of your naming

```
all_names = c("total costs","total current costs")
```

Then you can call this in a line similar to what you have

```
df1[,-which(df1[which(df1$col1 %in% all_names),]=="$")]

             col1 col2
1                 
2 total costs 1000
3   liability  50
```

You can build a small function with the code above and apply it to all your data frames:

```
clean_df = function(data){
  data[,-which(data[which(data$col1 %in% all_names),]=="$")]
}


lapply(list(df1,df2), clean_df)


[[1]]
         col1 col2
1                 
2 total costs 1000
3   liability  500

[[2]]
                 col1 col2
1                         
2 total current costs 1000
3           liability  500
```

If you encounter another naming and/or typo for the 'total' you can always add it to the initial vector

Comment: Nice. Thanks @bushidov. Much appreciated. If I want to replicate this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74859903/12210377), how do I approach -- `df %>%
  select(where(~ nzchar(.x[df$players %in% all_names])))`?